# Syntax or alternative solution for using the results of a sub-function within DATE_PART call of main function select

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a function that builds a table which is then updated by a scheduled module written in C#.  I want to move calculations away from the module into the function thereby making the module unnecessary.  The function calls a sub-function which retrieves info that is within a specified number of days (i.e. 30). The second "DATE_PART" call will not work as written due to syntax errors involving the variable name returned by sub-function "getpriorresponsedata".  I have greatly simplified the main function for the purpose of posting it but it was fine prior to the addition of "sub.r_interval" and the second DATE_PART call. The sub-function must remain unchanged.

```
select sub.id, 
       sub.reading_date, 
       sub.response_age, 
       (rInterval)."ReadingDate", 
       r_interval       
from (
  select d.id, 
         d.reading_date,    
         DATE_PART('day', now() - d.reading_date)::integer as response_age, 
        getintervalreading(d.id, 30) as rInterval,
        DATE_PART(‘day’, d.reading_date – (rInterval).”ReadingDate”)::integer as r_interval
   from table_device d 
   where d.active = true
) as sub;
```

This returns:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "–"
> LINE 14:    DATE_PART(‘day’, d.reading_date – (rInterval).”ReadingDat...
>                                             ^
> ```

The (simplified) sub-function is defined

```
FUNCTION public.getintervalreading(
         deviceid integer,
         intervaldays integer)
RETURNS TABLE("ReadingDate" date) 
LANGUAGE 'sql' COST 100 VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE ROWS 1000
```

With a body of

```
select rInterval.reading_date
from table_reading rInterval
where rInterval.device_id = deviceId 
        and rInterval.status = 'Valid' 
        and rInterval.reading_date > (current_date - intervaldays) 
order by rInterval.reading_date asc limit 1
```

My question is "Can I calculate r_interval using a value from the sub-function", if so what is the suggested syntax/method?

I have tried syntax variations using rInterval results within DATE_PART but have not hit on the right combo.  I have looked for examples that use sub-function results within CASE statements.

Comment: What data type is `rInterval`?

Comment: Thanks for the reformat.  rInterval is of type Table, containing various Dates, Integers and Numeric elements

Comment: If the function returns a `table` then you must use it as a table. Perhaps you need something like: `from mps_fp_device d join getintervalreading(d.id, 30) rInterval on ...'`. But without details  the function's parameters what it returns that cannot conclusively be determined.  Please update your question to provide those details including the function definition (or a stub that returns same)  also provide sample data and the expected results of that data, all as text - **no images**. or better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Thank you @Belayer, I probably am trying to do something unnatural with the table results.  I was able to feed (rInterval).”ReadingDate” into another function and return the value that I was looking for, but am leaving the question open in case someone sees something obvious.  I added snippet of function for review.